# Cystal reports with Linq2Sql

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, crystal-reports

I want to use Linq2Sql as the data source for my Crystal reports. I have all my data in my domain objects in the form of Lists. The problem is all my domain model resides in a different namespace in the form of a .dll. And when i try to assign a data source for my report in Database Expert window, under .NET Objects, i can only see classes that are available in the current project and not from other projects in my solution, nor from other namespaces.

Any solution or ideas how to deal with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I've done this, but try adding a static method that returns a List of the objects you want to use in the report, in a class that's contained in the same project as your report.